# Blocks spawning on mouse click does not register max block count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game, you need to place blocks in the game. I have the block placement working, however, only a certain amount of blocks are meant to be placed. I have set a value of blockMax but it doesn't seem to respond to it.

```
 public class SpawnBlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject block;
    public int blockMax;
    private int blockNum;

    void Update()
    {


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (blockNum < blockMax)
            {

                Vector3 spawnPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                spawnPos.z = 0f;

                GameObject objectSpawn = Instantiate(block, spawnPos, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)));

                blockNum++;

                Debug.Log("Number of Blocks = " + blockNum);
            }

            else if (blockNum >= blockMax)
            {
                Debug.Log("Reached Block Max");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried moving the order of the if statements around but it always gives the same result. In the GameObject window, it seems to be multiplying the number of blocks spawned each time it is pressed. Also, in the console log it resets the number of blocks registered and prints out the number of blocks it spawned that time.

This is the console log when the max was set to 3 and I clicked 4 times.

```
Number of Blocks = 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Number of Blocks = 2
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Number of Blocks = 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Reached Block Max
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:34)
Number of Blocks = 2
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Number of Blocks = 2
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Number of Blocks = 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Reached Block Max
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:34)
Reached Block Max
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:34)
Reached Block Max
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:34)
Number of Blocks = 2
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Number of Blocks = 2
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Number of Blocks = 2
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
Number of Blocks = 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SpawnBlock:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnBlock.cs:29)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the console output from clicking a few times when there are at first no blocks, and then clicking before during and after the block max should be reached? I'm asking because the code here seems like it should work, and there might be a clue in the console output about what else might be interfering.

Comment: I have just added the console log for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a `SpawnBlock` component attached to the `block` object you are spawning. Each time you spawn another block, you get another `SpawnBlock` that is looking for mouse clicks and keeping track of its own `blockNum` variable to spawn blocks.

The solution would be moving the `SpawnBlock` component off the `block` object and attaching it to an object there is never more than one of.

Comment: I had the sprite renderer and script on the same object, separated them and it's working now. Thank you!